# CNN does not work well on my dataset in Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, convolution, conv-neural-network

I want to apply the convolutional_mlp in theano to my own dataset. But the CNN cannot work well to my dataset, and I cannot find its reason. In the following, I will describe my datset in details, and can someone help me? Thanks so much!

The dataset:
My goal is to use the CNN to classify my images (whose size is 28*28 = 784) into two types, 0 and 1. 
My original data are the csv files, the datax.csv and datay.csv. In the datax.csv, each row stores the gray values of each pixel of each image, and in the datay.csv, each row is the label of each image. 
datax.csv (1000 rows, and 784 columns)

[image]

datay.csv (1000 rows)

```
0;1;1;0;1;0;1;1;1;0;1....
```

Based on the above csv data, I construct my dataset ('myDataset.pkl.gz') by the Python code as follows:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import gzip, cPickle
train_set_x = genfromtxt('data/1_datax.csv', delimiter=',')
train_set_y = genfromtxt('data/1_datay.csv', delimiter=',')
val_set_x = genfromtxt('data/2_datax.csv', delimiter=',')
val_set_y = genfromtxt('data/2_datay.csv', delimiter=',')
test_set_x = genfromtxt('data/3_datax.csv', delimiter=',')
test_set_y = genfromtxt('data/4_datay.csv', delimiter=',')

train_set = train_set_x, train_set_y
val_set = val_set_x, val_set_y
test_set = test_set_x, val_set_y

dataset = [train_set, val_set, test_set]


f = gzip.open('myDataset.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(dataset, f, protocol=2)
f.close()enter code here
```

After constructing my dataset, I use it in the convolutional_mlp.py, by replacing the mnist.pkl.gz. 
In my dataset, there are 1000 examples, 500 examples, and 500 examples in the training, validating, and testing datasets respectively. So in the convolutional_mlp.py, I set the batch_size as 500. Then there are 2 mini-batches, 1 mini-batch, and 1 mini-batch in the training, validating, and testing datasets respectively. Also I let the n_out be 2. Then I run the code, and print the training error of each epoch. The results are as follows:

[image]

No matter how many epochs it runs, the validation error never changes. In fact, I have changed the learning rate from 0.1, 0.01, 0.001,… But the results never changes. 
I will want to know why this will happen, can someone help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your training, validation and test datasets are entirely different from each other. I mean, it may be that your dataset is sorted on  some feature values or output, such that the training set and validation set do not have features common with each other. One example of such scenario is when you only have values from 0-3 in training set, 4-6 in validation set and 7-9 in test set for MNIST data partition.

It will work better if you read all the three datasets, shuffle them randomly and then split them into three sets. Generally, people use either 7:2:1 or 8:1:1 ratio of trianing size, validation size and test size. The model will learn better after such splitting and it will improve in accuracy.

Also, I would recommend you to use a smaller minibatch size, may be 32 or 64. That will lead to higher improvement in accuracy with each epoch. I hope it helps.